# Radian or Degrees?

Tags: c++, opengl, math

When I create matrix of rotation from Euler angles, Should I convert a degrees(Euler angles) to radians, and then count matrix of rotation for OpenGL? 
But what should I do with a quaternions?
Should I do following:

```
void setQuaternionsFromEuler(float bank, float heading, float attitude)
{
   float DegreeToRadian = 3.14f/180.0f;
   double c1 = cos(heading/2*DegreeToRadian);
   double c2 = cos(attitude/2*DegreeToRadian);
   //...
   double s3 = sin(bank/2*DegreeToRadian);

   this.w = c1*c2*c3 - s1*s2*s3;
   //...
}
```

And,

```
void setMatrixFromEuler(float x, float y, float z)
{
   float DegreeToRadian = 3.14f/180.0f;
   x *= DegreeToRadian;
   y *= DegreeToRadian;

   //...
}
```

Or not?

Comment: please use a more accurate value for π (M_PI) otherwise successive rotations that would normally result in the object reverting to its original location won't do so!

Comment: why use floats when you can have doubles?  wouldn't 16 significant digits be better than 7?

Comment: @duffymo opengl doesn't always accept doubles, floats are guaranteed

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It depends on how you define your input.

The trig functions of C++ take radian exclusively, so you need to convert to radian eventually but that may be done before the data even enters your program (such that the angle values in the resources are all in radian)

Answer (score 2):

Rotation matricies don't have angles anymore, so it's not really related with OpenGL, but the trigonometric functions you use from the standard library in C or C++ are defined on radians, so if your user-facing API works with degrees, then yes you should convert to take the cos/sin.